# Llenar una matriz con ciclo for con un if dentro c++

Tags: c++

Buenos días amigos de la comunidad, quisiera pedir su ayuda nuevamente, para poder entender algo, quiero que esto se cumpla

[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]

[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]

[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]

[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]

[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]

y así sucesivamente hasta que se cumplan 15 filas y 12 columnas, pero el chiste es que, al momento de que se cumple la fila 0 y la columna 0, en vez de ir del 0 al 11, a partir de la fila 1 columna 1 debería ir del 1 al 12, pero no logro hacerlo, les dejo mi código que funciona masomenos bien, pero no logro conseguirlo, muchas gracias compañeros, un saludo a todos.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[15][12];
    
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<12; j++){
            if(a[i][j]==0){
                a[i][j]=j;
            }else{
            a[i][j]=j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int x=0; x<15; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<12; y++){
            cout<<"["<<a[x][y]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque no simplificas el problema? no es necesario meter un if dentro del for...

Si vos sabes que la primera fila es diferente, entonces carga la primer fila y luego el resto...

Como nota, en tu codigo el error esta aca:

```
if(a[i][j]==0)
```

Como la matriz no esta inicializada, eso puede tener cualquier valor...

Y con esto que sigue cargas todo sin problemas...

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
    a[0][i]=i;
}
for(int i=1; i<15; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<12; j++){           
        a[i][j]=j+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) combinado con una lamba:

```
int indice = 0;
for (auto &fila : a)
    std::generate(std::begin(fila), std::end(fila),
        [n = static_cast<int>(indice++ != 0)]() mutable { return n++; });
```

La lambda usa una captura automática llamada `n` que vale cero en la primera fila y uno en las demás porque convertimos una operación booleana (`indice++ != 0`) a entero (`static_cast<int>`) y esa conversión implica que cero será `false` y `true` será uno.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDdaoQwEEavzVNMKVSDLXQLvVG7L2KlzMasDcTJEseFZfHZ7aj9o73LnBnmOxNzOj0Yj9TN860j48fWQoUx4mWvfoALA0eL/W@GvgvR8btA5YihR0eZVleVLBXWu@em3j01pdqAo9YZCy/wWKrkGCJkOHKAu6PzCAWgVkkycFsUnSUbkW22VgfbydplSN/DSiy1X3VNsm9gZGfeDA5cSdA@25LyHG4kTDeZhn5kPHgLV4iWx0hAeV7CpBe3VcUEGsT5W2jzkVP@t8/oBRWwKsjAJm3CyFBVsHXlkUJaqj/N9JUWOEnqp4f8xTTPHw)</kbd>.

Comment: que bonito cuando alguien que sabe contesta.. no entendi nada de tu respueesta.. pero debe ser 1000000 veces mejor que la mia :)

Comment: No es ni mejor ni peor, es una manera diferente de hacerlo, lo que pasa es que mi código usa 4 funcionalidades de C++ moderno: Bucle for de rango, funciones `begin` y `end` libres, lambdas mutables y capturas automáticas en lambda.